# Python Code to Create Sum of Neighbors and itself in the original list

Tags: python, list

> Question: Given a list of integers, write python code to create a new list with the same number of elements as the original list such that each integer in the new list is the sum of its neighbors and itself in the original list. Example: is listA = [10,20,30,40,50], listB = [30,60,90,120,90]

I'm struggling with finding the right way to set up this code. I know how to define the function but how do you set up the adding of neighbor integers/itself? Any help would be appreciated.

What I have so far:

```
def sumNeighbors(list, start = 0, end =None):
    if end is None:
       end = len(list)

sum = 0
i = start
while i < end:
    sum += list[i]
    i += 1
return sum

text = raw_input ("Enter an integer (period to end): ")
list = []
while text != '.':
    textInt = int(text)
    list.append(textInt)
    text = raw_input("Enter an integer (period to end): ")

print "List: ", list
print "sum: ", sumNeighbors(list)
```

Comment: show us what you've tried so far

Comment: You iterate over the list and get the value of the current, previous and following element. Is that what you wanted to know?

Comment: Be careful with python negative list access: *listA[-1] == 50*, and not an error as most languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just special cased the ends of the list.  Basically, at the start of the list, you only want add the right neighbor, and at the end of the list, you only want to add the left neighbor.

So, I start by appending the first item which is just the value at index 0 + the value at index 1.

`new_list.append(list[0] + list[1])`

Then, I use a while loop to iterate through all the middle indexes.

For each of those, we are summing `list[x - 1] + list[x] + list[x + 1]`

Careful to start summing the middle with index 1, not 0, as 0 was already special cased.  Then make sure you don't go off the end, by using a for loop that goes to `len(list) - 1`.  For the last item, you just sum `list[x - 1] + list[x]`

Here's the whole code:

```
def sum_neighbors(list):
    new_list = []
    new_list.append(list[0] + list[1])
    x = 1
    while x < len(list) - 1:
        new_list.append(list[x - 1] + list[x] + list[x + 1])
        x += 1
    new_list.append(list[x - 1] + list[x])

    return new_list
```

Comment: Thank you! You're help combined everything everyone else said in a visual way. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up an iteration.

```
>>> listA = [10,20,30,40,50]
>>> for index, item in enumerate(listA):
...   print 'I am at index {} and the current item is {}'.format(index, item)
... 
I am at index 0 and the current item is 10
I am at index 1 and the current item is 20
I am at index 2 and the current item is 30
I am at index 3 and the current item is 40
I am at index 4 and the current item is 50
```

So now you want to add some extra logic into that loop:

```
listB = []

for index, item in enumerate(listA):
  print 'I am at index {} and the current item is {}'.format(index, item)
  # The item at the previous index is.. ???'
  # The item at the next index is.. ???'
  # Find the sum of these three items.  
  # Be careful about the endpoints of the listA.  
  listB.append(something)
```

Answer (score 2):

Ask for it directly: you want a list of the sum of (a value drawn from a list consisting of `0` followed by all the elements of the original list except the last; a value drawn from the original list; and a value drawn from a list consisting of all the elements of hte original list except the first, followed by `0`), taken elementwise.

In Python, that is spelled:

```
[sum(z) for z in zip([0] + original[:-1], original, original[1:] + [0])]
```

Comment: Nice! Clearly better than what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

A standard `for x in list` loop won't work here, because that doesn't let you see the neighbors. Two alternative idioms are:

- `for i, x in enumerate(list)` -- this will set `i` to `0` and `x` to `list[0]`, then similarly over the rest of the list
- `for i in xrange(len(list))` (or just `range` in Python 3): this will just give you 0, 1, ..., `len(list) - 1`.

`enumerate` is more Pythonic, but `xrange` is fine here too.

Once you have the loop working, you just have to worry about finding the neighbors based on `i` and adding them together.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the same idea as in other posts. You have to treat the first and the last item separately. My for loop is ugly, but it avoids the use of indexes.

```
def sum_neighbors(listA):

    listB = []

    listB.append(listA[0] + listA[1])

    for ele_prev, ele, ele_next in zip(listA[0:len(listA)-2],listA[1:len(listA)-1],listA[2:len(listA)]):
        listB.append(ele_prev + ele + ele_next)

    listB.append(listA[len(listA)-1] + listA[len(listA)-2])

    return listB

print sum_neighbors(listA)
```

Answer (score 0):

A method that I like is:

```
def sumNeighbors(list1, start = 0, end = None):
    if end is None:
        myend = len(list1)
    loclist = list1[start:myend] # Copy the list.
    loclist.insert(0,0) # Put a 0 at the start of the local list...
    loclist.append(0) # ...and at the end.
    return [sum((a,b,c)) for a,b,c in zip(loclist[1:-1],loclist[:-2],loclist[2:])]
```

Another method which also allows you to generate the sums one at a time is:

```
def genSums(list1):
    loclist = list1[:] # Copy the list.
    e1 = loclist.pop(0) # Get the first two entries.
    e2 = loclist.pop(0)
    yield e1+e2 # Return the first sum.
    e3 = 0 # Initialize e3 so it isn't None
    while e3 is not None:
        try:
            e3 = loclist.pop(0) # Assign e3 if the list isn't empty.
        except IndexError:
            break # If the list is empty, break out of the loop.
        yield e1+e2+e3 # Return the sum.
        e1,e2 = e2,e3
    yield e1+e2 # Return the last sum.

sumNeighbors = [x for x in genSums(list[start:end])] # Equivalent to the function.
```